# Grouping of text in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, text-classification

Hello guys i am new to NLP and am totally lost. All help is much appreciated.I Have data set of dimension 5000x3. So my first column is the a timestamp and the second column is Title of the essay. I need to group them into similar titles and introduce a third column with a group number based on the title similarity and newness and frequency of  the topics occurrance . Can anyone help me with this?

```
this is how my data set looks
    Timestamp       Essaytitle               
    20156032125     life of Pablo           
    21056032127     Plays of Shakespeare    
    21056032127     French Revolution
```

This is what ive done : 1. NLP preprocessing(tokenization and stop word removal in the essay column). 2. tf_idf vectorize 3.Cosinesimilarity 4.k means clustering based off cosine similarity. I'm pretty sure what is doing is wrong. Help!!!!

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
token = RegexpTokenizer(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+')
tf=TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=True,stop_words=words,ngram_range = (1,1),tokenizer = token.tokenize)

 data['EssayTitle']=data['EssayTitle'].astype(str)
EssayTitle_tf_idf=tf.fit_transform(data['EssayTitle'])
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
sim=cosine_similarity(EssayTitle_tf_idf)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

true_k = 2
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k)
model.fit(EssayTitle_tf_idf)
clusters = model.labels_.tolist()
data['Clusters']=clusters
data['Clusters'].value_counts()

My expected output should be:
 Timestamp       Essaytitle           Group
20156032125     Shakespeare             2
21056032127     Plays of Shakespeare    2
21056032127     French Revolution       1
```

Comment: are u try to using k-mean to classify group of text right ?

Comment: they do not have labels so i assumed i could use k means clustering